# Appropriate model for count data when response variable minimum value is far above zero

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, count-data, poisson-regression, overdispersion

**CASE 1:** I am trying to model count data; the response variable, y=c(12, 15, 34, 13, 12, 33,....,45) while the explanatory variables are location (binary, rural/urban), marital status, education level, etc. minimum value of y=12 and max. value =45.

**CASE 2:** 
the response variable, y=c(201345, 763015, 753412, 820113, 120127, 413387,....,456171) - {six digits each value} while the explanatory variables are continuous variables.

Can I used the likes of Zero-truncated Poisson or ZTNB models while more than zero are not possible in the design of the research?

Comment: I don't see why using them would cause any problems, but there would probably not be  be any meaningful difference from a model with an untruncated distribution.